# HttpError 403 while sharing posts on Google+

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to insert posts into my own `Google+` profile via `Python API`, however I have been failing all the time. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating). I activated `Google+ Domains API` and `Google+ API` and created native application credentials for the example in the tutorial.

Following code snippet shows how I post to `Google API`:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write']
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                           scope=SCOPES,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Please paste this URL in your browser to authenticate this program.'
print auth_uri
code = raw_input('Enter the code it gives you here: ')
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)
user_id = 'me'
result = service.activities().insert(
    userId = user_id,
    body = {
        'object' : {
            'originalContent' : 'Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays'
        },
        'access' : {
            'items' : [{
                'type' : 'domain'
            }],
            'domainRestricted': True
        }
    }).execute()
```

Request returns an error below:

> apiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?alt=json
>   returned "Forbidden">

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

I'm giving consent in the browser to be able to write posts Why would it be forbidden?

Comment: Are you signing in with a Google Apps account? This won't work for normal Gmail accounts.

Comment: No, I'm not. Is there another api which works with normal Gmail accounts? I just want to post to my "page" automatically. Any idea is welcome

Comment: The Domains API is restricted to Google Apps accounts. There is a [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) but access is limited.

Comment: Thanks for this, let me try to apply for it.